# Mysql value to PHP variable in MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function and it work's correctly:

```
function update_currencies_rates($currency_rate)
{
    
    $this->db->set('main_rate', 'CASE
   
    WHEN type = "Fiat main" THEN ' . $currency_rate["BTC-USD"]["ask"] . '
    
    END', FALSE);
    
    $this->db->set('last_update_time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    
    $this->db->update('currencies');
    
}
```

But instead of `USD` in `$currency_rate["BTC-USD"]["ask"]` I want to insert a value from MySQL column called `code`.

So, I tried this but it is not work:

```
WHEN type = "Fiat main" THEN ' . $currency_rate["BTC- . ' code ' . "]["ask"] . '
```

How can I use a value of column `code` instead of USD?

Comment: You can't use a MySQL value there, because the PHP code is constructing the query first.

Comment: @Barmar I edited the code, thanks.

Comment: You need to do a query first to get the value of `code`, set the variable `$code` to that, then you can use `$currency_rate["BTC-" . $code]["ask"]` in the next query.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but I think it won't help because $currency_rate is array of many currency rates and in every row of 'main_rate' column I need to insert they own currency rate according to value of 'code' column of this row.

Comment: You need to loop through all the results, and do a separate `UPDATE` for each one using the appropriate rate. Can you put the currency rates in a table in the DB? Then you could use `UPDATE + JOIN` to related them.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for answer, but unfortunately I can not put JSON array result to DB before this, because this function should to do exactly that - add the needed currency rates to DB table.